# javascript socket server is overwriting variables

Tags: javascript, sockets, asynchronous

I have a socket server that receives data packets from machines in an industrial environment. as the packets come in, I process them via async / await functions.
The problem is, some of my variables are being overwritten (I believe) in the process and I do not know what is causing it.

here is the code that calls the function
`const advancedSpeedFunctionResult = await writeAdvancedSpeed(packet);`

and some of the code that processes it:

```
async function writeAdvancedSpeed(packet) {
  const { statusSensor, packetId, message } = packet;

  logger.verbose(`[advSpd] [_${statusSensor.monitor}_] running writeAdvancedSpeed`);
  let on;
  let off;

  if (packetId == 59) {
    on = message[4] + (message[5] << 8);
    off = message[6] + (message[7] << 8);
  } else {
    on = (message[14] << 8) + message[13];
    off = (message[16] << 8) + message[15];
  }
  logger.verbose(`[advSpd] [_${statusSensor.monitor}_]     initial on: ${on} | off: ${off}`);

  const cycleTimer = await CycleTimer.query().findOne({ monitor: statusSensor.monitor });

  if (cycleTimer) {
    let speed;
    if (on + off < 1) {
      speed = 0.0;
      logger.verbose(`[advSpd] [_${statusSensor.monitor}_]     on + off < 1 set speed to ${speed}`);
    } else {
      speed = (on * 100.0) / (on + off);
      logger.verbose(
        `[advSpd] [_${statusSensor.monitor}_]     (on: ${on} * 100) / (on: ${on} + off: ${off}) = set speed to ${speed}`
      );
    }

    logger.verbose(`[advSpd] [_${statusSensor.monitor}_]     speed before rounding ${speed}`);
```

yet, here is what I am getting in the logs
note the zero speed that should not exist

```
2021-06-19 07:54:49:489<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_] running writeAdvancedSpeed                                                                                                                                
 5570 2021-06-19 07:54:49:489<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_]     initial on: 8300 | off: 51700                                                                                                                         
 5571 2021-06-19 07:54:49:490<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_]     speed before rounding 13.833333333333334                                                                                                              
 5572 2021-06-19 07:54:49:490<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_]     speed after rounding 13.833333333333334                                                                                                               
 5573 2021-06-19 07:54:49:490<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_]     cycle_timer_id = 5441 writing on: 8300 | off: 51700 | speed 13.833333333333334                                                                        
 5574 2021-06-19 07:54:49:495<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_]     writing advanced speed hit                                                                                                                            
 5575 2021-06-19 07:55:40:875<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_] running writeAdvancedSpeed                                                                                                                                
 5576 2021-06-19 07:55:40:875<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_]     initial on: 8300 | off: 51700                                                                                                                         
 5577 2021-06-19 07:55:40:878<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_]     speed before rounding 13.833333333333334                                                                                                              
 5578 2021-06-19 07:55:40:878<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_]     speed after rounding 13.833333333333334                                                                                                               
 5579 2021-06-19 07:55:40:878<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_]     cycle_timer_id = 5441 writing on: 8300 | off: 51700 | speed 13.833333333333334                                                                        
 5580 2021-06-19 07:55:40:902<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_]     writing advanced speed hit                                                                                                                            
 5581 2021-06-19 07:55:48:139<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_] running writeAdvancedSpeed                                                                                                                                
 5582 2021-06-19 07:55:48:139<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_]     initial on: 8300 | off: 51700                                                                                                                         
 5583 2021-06-19 07:55:48:140<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_]     speed before rounding 0                                                                                                                               
 5584 2021-06-19 07:55:48:140<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_]     speed after rounding 0                                                                                                                                
 5585 2021-06-19 07:55:48:140<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_]     cycle_timer_id = 5441 writing on: 0 | off: 0 | speed 0                                                                                                
 5586 2021-06-19 07:55:48:158<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_]     writing advanced speed hit                                                                                                                            
 5587 2021-06-19 07:55:53:433<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_] running writeAdvancedSpeed                                                                                                                                
 5588 2021-06-19 07:55:53:433<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_]     initial on: 8300 | off: 51700                                                                                                                         
 5589 2021-06-19 07:55:53:434<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_]     speed before rounding 13.833333333333334                                                                                                              
 5590 2021-06-19 07:55:53:434<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_]     speed after rounding 13.833333333333334                                                                                                               
 5591 2021-06-19 07:55:53:434<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_]     cycle_timer_id = 5441 writing on: 8300 | off: 51700 | speed 13.833333333333334                                                                        
 5592 2021-06-19 07:55:53:467<>verbose: [advSpd] [_5929b_]     writing advanced speed hit
```

if this problem is fixed here, it will also fix some other areas of my code where similar things happen. Is this caused by perhaps other packets coming in with these values? Somehow they are getting cross-misplaced or held in memory and written here? This log only shows the results of this machine reporting in, but hundreds are per minute.

some of the conflicts were resolved by using more const than let..
but not all.

Comment: The code that you've shown looks to be threadsafe, but maybe there's a thread safety problem in statusSensor or CycleTimer? Or other code that you're not showing?

Comment: statusSensor is an instance of StatusSensor from the objection.js ORM. CycleTimer is a class of the same project. They are models in the database. However, I will check the code for any processes done on the statusSensor  that may be breaking things. Also will research thread safety on javascript async ops. Thanks for your help